# удаление записи в таблице без потери в другой

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

Есть таблица Orders Products казалось бы связь один ко многим, в одном заказе много продуктов, но если я хочу удалить запись в продуктах, и не хочу потерять запись в таблице заказы.
 
как сделать связи?

---

Спасибо большое всем, я понял что делать.

Comment: *как сделать связи?* Без каскадных операций. *как сделать* Забыть об удалении записей из таблицы продуктов, дополнительно ввести в неё поле валидности.

Comment: А как вы потом определите, на какой продукт был заказ? Если название продукта все-равно храните в заказе - лучший способ сделать такую связь - это вообще не делать связь...

Comment: Предпочитаю в подобных случаях (корпоративные системы) ставить пометку на удаление (IsDeleted, IsHidden, IsArchieved и т.п.) и проводить раз в квартал процедуру проверки ссылочной целостности. Нелюбимая многими 1Ска делает это штатно из коробки, кастомные CRM'ки нужно пилить такую фичу.

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, выбранное вами решение. Это может быть полезно другим участникам проекта.

Comment: Видимо один я не понял о чем речь. <в одном заказе много продуктов, но если я хочу удалить запись в продуктах, и не хочу потерять запись в таблице заказы> А в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: @Orthodox Есть заказ из продуктов A, B и C. Спустя какое-то время продукт А удаляется из таблицы, соответственно, в этом заказе остаются ссылки только на B и C. Потом клиент решает посмотреть свою историю заказов, и удивляется. Вот тут-то и возникает проблема.

Comment: @Yaant спасибо, я понял. Я не мог предположить, что так делают.

Answer (score 1):

Предпочитаю в подобных случаях (корпоративные системы) ставить пометку на удаление (IsDeleted, IsHidden, IsArchieved и т.п.) и проводить раз в квартал процедуру проверки ссылочной целостности.

Нелюбимая многими 1Ска делает это штатно из коробки, кастомные CRM'ки нужно пилить такую фичу.